# androiddeployqt: Qt hook gradle android

Tags: android, qt, gradle, qmake

I want to use third-party libraries in my Qt/Android project. In typical android project I have to add `compile` to `dependencies` list, however it's impossible for Qt, because `build.gradle` is generated by `androiddeployqt`.

[Docs says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android3rdpartylibs.html) I should use `project.properties` for this, but it doesn't make any sense, because its support has been dropped since Android Studio. Moreover, I don't want to recompile all libraries on my own when using gradle.

So the question is: is it possible to hook androiddeployqt somehow to add few lines into `build.gradle`? Or maybe it's possible to put another `build.gradle` into subdir and gradle will execute tasks from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is put `build.gradle` neat `AndroidManifest.xml` file with content like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.5.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.5.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.5.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```